# Make div height respond to content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `div` which is being filled `using .text()` method but when I enter a long text entry, the height of the div doesn't respond and the text overflows the `div`.

I have a `textarea` and a button, when the button is pressed the value of the text area is inserted into the div.

IMAGE: http://prntscr.com/et5ja5

## Things tried:

```
Height: auto;
display: inline-block;
overflow: visible/auto; etc
```

## FULL EXAMPLE UPON REQUEST

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="article1">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Notes</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="addContainer">
                <button id="addNoteBtn" data-role="button">Add Note</button>
                <textarea id="noteInput" class="textarea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

                <button id="savenotesbtn" data-role="button">Save</button>-->
            </div>
            <div id="displayContainer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#addContainer {
     margin: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
}
 #displayContainer {
     margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
 .noteDisplay {
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     background-color: #96c56f;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 5px, 0px, 5px, 0px;
     border: solid 2px black;
     border-radius: 5px;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
}
 .textarea {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     font: 1em arial;
     color: rgba(50, 82, 50, 1.0);
}
 .textarea:focus {
     color: rgba(50, 82, 50, 1.0);
     border: 2px solid #96c56f;
     box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #888888;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var savesnotesbtn = document.getElementById("savenotesbtn");
    var addnotebtn = document.getElementById("addNoteBtn");

    var noteCount = localStorage.getItem("noteCount");

    if (noteCount === null) {
        noteCount = 0;
    }
    addnotebtn.addEventListener("click", addNotes);

    //ADD NOTES
    function addNotes() {
        noteCount++;
        var note = $("#noteInput").val();
        console.log("Note: " + note);
        console.log("Note Count: " + noteCount);
        var display = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById("displayContainer").appendChild(display);
        display.className = "noteDisplay";
        display.id = "note" + noteCount;
        $("#note" + noteCount).text(note);

        localStorage.setItem("noteCount", noteCount);
    }
});
```

Comment: provide html tooo or working example

Comment: will add shortly, thanks

Comment: your jquery code is not working .. please provide a full working example.

Comment: @SahilDhir That should be everything now, the only stuff i've removed is footer navigation and other pages etc

Comment: How does it overflow? .. at the bottom, the right.....?

Comment: It overflows to the right of the div, basically if the text is longer than the width of the div then the text continues to the right instead of moving to the next line.

Comment: I will try to add an image but currently on a public PC without gyazo or something installed

Comment: @LGSon http://prntscr.com/et5ja5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment from OP, saying *it overflows to the right of the div*, if one add `word-break: break-all` to the `noteDisplay` rule it will break line properly

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjkwdcqk/1/)

```
.noteDisplay {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: #96c56f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px, 0px, 5px, 0px;
    border: solid 2px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    word-break: break-all;          /*  added property  */
}
```

---

Regarding the difference between `break-all` and `break-word`, when text is entered in  Chinese, Japanese, and Korean, it is better distributed on each line with `break-all`

Src:  https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#break-all

Comment: @EthanBristow You're welcome, and if users will write in Chinese, Japanese, and Korean, you will need to use the `break-all` I used in my answer, as `break-word` won't work the same

Answer (score 2):

Try `word-wrap: break-word;` for the css, that should do the trick.

(providing html code would be useful and an image of the overflowing text)

All you need to know about overflow in css, you can find it here : http://www.codelord.net/2013/08/23/css-tip-overflowing-with-text/.

### Here's the working example

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var savesnotesbtn = document.getElementById("savenotesbtn");
    var addnotebtn = document.getElementById("addNoteBtn");

    //var noteCount = localStorage.getItem("noteCount");

    if (noteCount === null) {
      var noteCount = 0;
    }


    addnotebtn.addEventListener("click", addNotes);

    //ADD NOTES
    function addNotes() {
        noteCount++;
        var note = $("#noteInput").val();
        //console.log("Note: " + note);
        //console.log("Note Count: " + noteCount);
        var display = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById("displayContainer").appendChild(display);
        display.className = "noteDisplay";
        display.id = "note" + noteCount;
        $("#note" + noteCount).text(note);

        //localStorage.setItem("noteCount", noteCount);
    }
});
```

```css
#addContainer {
    margin: 20px 20px 50px 20px;
}

#displayContainer {
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.noteDisplay {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background-color: #96c56f;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px, 0px, 5px, 0px;
    border: solid 2px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font: 1em arial;
    color: rgba(50, 82, 50, 1.0);
}

.textarea:focus {
    color: rgba(50, 82, 50, 1.0);
    border: 2px solid #96c56f;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #888888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="article1">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Notes</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <div id="addContainer">
                    <button id="addNoteBtn" data-role="button">Add Note</button>
                    <textarea id="noteInput" class="textarea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

                    <button id="savenotesbtn" data-role="button">Save</button>-->
                </div>
                <div id="displayContainer">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: more like a comment. use comment area.

Comment: @Jai Sadly, I can't comment yet (trying to reach 50). But I do think this is a possible answer and should work. An image and html code would be useful.

Comment: then try to earn some reps then try to comment. You can put better answers, ask questions which can let you get some reps.

Comment: @Jai You seem to imply that my answer won't help, but it seems like a reasonable solution. Let's see what the author says. But thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Xogno When the question lack enough info to be answerable, any answer will be a lucky guess, and no one benefit from a that, hence one use a comment until it is clear what the issue is and how it can be solved

Comment: @LGSon I completely agree with you. Though this time, with the ecplanation he gave, I was pretty sure about myself. I illustrated my answer with a working example. Please check it and remove downvote and put upvote if it seems good to you :)

Comment: Two correct answers so thank you both, can only accept one though

Comment: Sure Man :) :) :)

Comment: Accept @Xongo answer

Comment: The working sample you provide came 30 min after the first _guess_, hence my down vote, which I will remove now since it is clear what the issue were. An upvote you'll get next time, when you don't guess and wait until a proper answer can be given to a proper question

Comment: @LGSon Fair enough, learned my lesson. By the way, I can comment now. So I won't have that problem anymore, I'll be able to ask the author directly for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

**`word-wrap:break-word`  will solve the problem.**

> Add this to your

`.noteDisplay{word-wrap:break-word}`